# Google Map API tilt is not working in given LatLng

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, leaflet

I am using leaflet.google.js for google map. I have done tilt:45  in initMapObject function. On map this is working for some other location(latlang) but not tilt with my require location(40.4134741, -74.3057727).
I have checked same latlang with maps.google.com and It is tilt(giving button 2D/3D).
Please review my code with link.

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/fJFWN/211/"
```

Please Help me I need tilt view in my given location.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The official Google Maps JavaScript API documentation says

> The Google Maps JavaScript API supports special 45° imagery for **certain locations**. This high-resolution imagery provides perspective views towards each of the cardinal direction (North, South, East, West). These images are available at higher zoom levels for supported map types.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#45DegreeImagery

I understand aerial imagery is not available everywhere in JavaScript API, it looks like it's not available at 40.4134741, -74.3057727.

Also note that the Google Maps website is a different product managed by different team at Google, so you cannot expect exactly the same behavior in Maps JavaScript API and maps.google.com.

I hope this explains your doubt.